# state loading issue (javascript loads before templateUrl)

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS to load forms and having 2 issues

- JS files loads before templateUrl
- When I move to new View then JavaScript functions in old views are also accessible.

Please have a look at attached code:

```js
.state('index.categdashboard', {
            url: "/categdashboard",
            templateUrl: "views/categdashboard.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Category wise Headcount - Dashboard' },
   controller: 'getCategoryWiseSummary',
   resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {
                            files: [
                                 // Row 1
                                 'js/categdashboard/categdashboard.js', 
                                 ],
                            cache: false
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
```

I have tried

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
```

but it also did not worked

Answer (score 0):

I declared a new controller in my new view and called the JavaScript functions from it.

```js
angular
 .controller('MainDashboardCtrl', MainDashboardCtrl)


function MainDashboardCtrl(){
 // Called functions here
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainDashboardCtrl as MDCtrl">
</div>
```